# JaxWS application URL in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jax-ws

I do not know how to change URL of my JAX-WS WebService on Tomcat.

localhost:8080/WSCalc/WSCalc?wsdl run ok but I would like to change URL to localhost:8080/ws/WSCalc/WSCalc?wsdl

With configuration below I can run localhost:8080/ws/WSCalc/ (it is index.jsp) but I can not run WebService localhost:8080/ws/WSCalc/WSCalc?wsdl (it returns 404)

Directory webapps/ includes:

```
WSCalc.war
WSCalc/
-index.jsp
-META-INF/context.xml
-WEB-INF/web.xml
-WEB-INF/sun-jaxws.xml
-WEB-INF/classes/*
-WEB-INF/lib/*
```

web.xml:

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>WSCalc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>WSCalc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/WSCalc</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

sun-jaxws.xml:

```
<endpoints version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime">
  <endpoint implementation="cz.vrana.WSCalc" name="WSCalc" url-pattern="/WSCalc"/>
</endpoints>
```

server.xml:

```
<Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWars="true" autodeploy=""true">
     <Context path="/ws" docBase="." />
</Host>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `<url-pattern>/ws/WSCalc</url-pattern>`?

You are getting a 404 because in web.xml there is no servlet mapping to /ws/WSCalc.

Comment: It does not work. I have tried it. Result was HTTP request status: 404 (Not Found).

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need is to change the context of application deployment. For this, see [The Context Container](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html).

In another hand, for the pattern mapping, you can change in the `web.xml` for all path starting with `/WSCalc/`

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>WSCalc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/WSCalc/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Or if you want a single pattern

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>WSCalc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/WSCalc/WSCalc</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In the sun-jaxws.xml change to

```
<endpoint ... url-pattern="/WSCalc/WSCalc" />
```

Comment: I have discovered ws#WSCalc.war will auto-deploy application on localhost:8080/ws/WSCalc/WSCalc?wsdl. That's great. But I would like to deploy WSCalc.war automatically on /ws/WSCacl/... I am ineffective to configure context container.