# Change JAX-WS listening url

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish

Alright, this might look like a duplicate question but I have struggled a lot but haven't found a proper solution. Closest match I found is this: [JaxWS application URL in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15406842/jaxws-application-url-in-tomcat)
But this is using something different.

I am using Glassfish 3 and developing in Netbeans 7.4 along with Spring, Spring MVC. I have developed my webservice using following code:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "FooService")
public class FooWS {

   @WebMethod(operationName="getHelloWorld")
   public String getHelloWorld() {
        return "Hi";
   }
}
```

Now the problem is that, it start listening at this address `http://localhost:8080/myapp/FooService`

But I want it to listen at `http://localhost:8080/myapp/ws/FooService`.
I do not have any xml in my project for configuring web services. I only have following xmls in `WEB-INF`

1. applicationContext.xml
2. dispatcherServlet.xml
3. glassfish-web.xml
4. spring-security.xml
5. web.xml

Except `glassfish-web.xml` netbeans haven't generated any code for my webservice in any other xml file. And also in this file there is no source, just there is a section for Web Services which shows this web service, I am attaching image for the same.

[image: Netbeans screen-shot for glassfish-web.xml section for webservices]

Does anybody knows where should I make changes to change listening url? Or any annotation that might help?

I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8975619/601168 but I guess this is for clients only.